# Show that Vandermonde-like $3 \times 3$ determinant is non-zero

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives

I want to show that the determinant
$$
   f(t)=\det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & x^t \\
                             1 & y & y^t \\
                             1 & z & z^t
     \end{bmatrix}
$$
is nonzero for all $t \neq 0$, $1$ if $x$, $y$, $z$ are mutually distinct positive numbers. It can be seen that $2\times 2$ minors are nonzero. Now suppose, on the contrary, that $f(t) = 0$. Then there exist real nonzero $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ such that
$$
   \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1, \\
   \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 y = z, \\
   \lambda_1 x^t + \lambda_2 y^t = z^t.
$$
From the first two equations we find
$$
   \lambda_1 = \frac{y - z}{y-x}, \; \lambda_2 = \frac{z - x}{y-x},
$$
and from the first and last:
$$
   \lambda_1 = \frac{y^t-z^t}{y^t-x^t}, \; \lambda_2 = \frac{z^t-x^t}{y^t-x^t}.
$$
It implies that
$$
   \frac{q^t - 1}{p^t - 1} = \frac{q-1}{p-1},\quad q = \frac{z}{y}, \; p = \frac{x}{y}.
$$
Without loss of generality we can suppose that $p < 1 < q$. It is sufficient to show that the map
$$
   g(t) = \frac{q^t-1}{p^t-1}
$$
is strictly decreasing. It is true in all the examples that I checked in Wolfram Alpha. The straightforward way to show that the map is decreasing is to compute $g'(t)$ and to show that $g'(t) < 0$ for all $t$. But this requires a lot of technical work, the arising expressions are huge. My question is whether it is possible to solve the initial problem using some other considerations or maybe there is an easy (technically) way to show that $g'(t)<0$?

Comment: I think the case $1 \lt p \lt q$ would be more tractable, as we can then take a logarithm and simplify some of the computation (taking derivative of $\ln g(t)$ to show it increasing with $t$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi_t \colon x \mapsto x^t$.

For $t > 1$, the function $\varphi_t$ is strictly convex, for $0 < t < 1$, it is strictly concave, and for $t < 0$, it is strictly convex.

By the strict convexity resp. concavity, if we have

$$z = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y,$$

then we have, under the assumption $0 < \lambda < 1$ and $x\neq y$, the strict inequality

$$\varphi_t(z) = \varphi_t(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \lessgtr \lambda \varphi_t(x) + (1-\lambda)\varphi_t(y)$$

by the definition of (strict) convexity/concavity. If $\lambda < 0$ or $\lambda > 1$, the sense of the inequality is reversed, but the strictness of the inequality is preserved.

Hence, for $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1\}$, we have $f(t) = 0$ if and only if at least two of $x,y,z$ are equal.